# Split a range of number to a specific number of intervals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an interval `[0; max]` and I want to split it into a specific number of sub-intervals. For this, i wrote a function called `getIntervalls(max, nbIntervals)` where `max` is the max element in my first interval and `nbIntervals` is the number of expected sub-intervals.

For example:

- `getIntervalls(3, 2)` should return `[[0,1], [2,3]]`,
- `getIntervalls(6, 2)` should return `[[0,3], [4,6]]`,
- `getIntervalls(8, 3)` should return `[[0,2], [3,5], [6,8]]`,
- `getIntervalls(9, 3)` should return `[[0,3], [4,7], [8,9]]`,

Here is my function:

```
function getIntervalls(max, nbIntervalls) {

    var size = Math.ceil(max / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];

    if (size > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        var inf = i + i * size;
        var sup = inf + size < max ? inf + size: max;

        result .push([inf, sup]);
      }
    } else {
      result.push([0, max]);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(7, 2)));
```

It work properly, and shows this output:

```
[[0,4],[5,7]]
```

When I change the parameters to 7 and 3, it shows:

```
[[0,3],[4,7],[8,7]]
```

instead of

```
[[0,2],[3,5],[6,7]]
```

Would anyone can help me? Thank you in advance. An ES6 syntax will be appreciated! :)

Comment: I would like to replicate your problem locally first, can you edit your question to include the values your working with and I will analise the fault better. Whilst I can create an array of my own, it may not replicate the same and thus i would be assuming something which I am trying to avoid

Comment: This is simply a case of `math.ceil` vs `math.floor`. `7/3 == 2.3333` which rounds up to `3` giving you your observed output. `math.floor` rounds down to `2` giving you the desired output.

Comment: Also, there's one more error. I think you meant `if (size > 1)` to be `if (nbIntervalls > 1)` - otherwise your first test case `getIntervalls(3, 2)` won't work after fixing the `ceil` vs `floor` problem.

Comment: If `getIntervalls(3, 2)` should return `[[0,1], [2,3]]`, shouldn't then `getIntervalls(7, 2)` return `[[0,3],[4,7]]`?

Comment: You've made the solution far too hard, I think -- a relatively simple list comprehension should make this a one-liner.  I can't canonize one, however, as I don't understand the logic behind your splits.  The last example, for `(9, 3)`, lists intervals of non-contiguous sizes: you have two intervals of size 4, and the last of size 2.  How is this supposed to work???

Comment: @Prune it is normal, all the sub-intervals should have the same size, except the last, which can have the same or less than the others' size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if `i` is zero for first element and if next increment is larger then max for second element. Also you can check if first element is smaller then max.

```js
function getIntervalls(max, nInt) {
  const c = Math.floor(max / nInt);
  const r = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= max; i += c) {
    const a = i == 0 ? i : i += 1;
    const b = i + c > max ? max : i + c;
    if (a < max) r.push([a, b])
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(3, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(6, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(8, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(9, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(7, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(7, 3)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and improvement, it works fine!

Comment: Only one exception, when I want to `getIntervalls(19, 5)` , it returns `[[0,4],[5,9],[10,14],[15,19]]` so I removed the condition before pushing

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Math.round()` for take the nearest integer of the decimal number of the `size` of interval. Also, you need to descrease a one the `max` for `size` calculation to take account of the effective number of interval.

Here the modification of your code :

```
function getIntervalls(max, nbIntervalls) {
    var size = Math.round((max-1) / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        var inf = i + i * size;
        var sup = inf + size < max ? inf + size: max;

        result.push([inf, sup]);
        if(inf >= max || sup >= max)break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that it respect the wanted number of interval, so some case of couple of number can result  
`[..., [n-2,n-1], [n,n]]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, simmingly it works fine, but when I call `getIntervalls(7,5)` it returns `[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,7]]`. The last sub-interval is invalid.

Comment: To avoid intervals greater than `max`, i added the `if(inf >= max || sup >= max)break;` break condition

Comment: Thank you for your intervention, I find your condition correct but misplaced. It should be better to put it before pushing your sub-interval into `result` array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the size calculation from `Math.ceil()` to `Math.floor()`, because of `ceil` it takes size +1 than what you need.

I have made modification to your code, here it will work.

```
function getIntervalls(max, nbIntervalls) {

    var size = Math.floor(max / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];

    if (size > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        var inf = i + i * size;
        var sup = inf + size < max ? inf + size : max;

        result .push([inf, sup]);
        if (sup >= max) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      result.push([0, max]);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getIntervalls(10, 5)));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `getIntervalls(3, 2)` won't work with this code. The `if (size > 1)` is a mistake.

Comment: @MattBurland yes you are correct, missed a corner case there, thanks, made a fix to it, now hopefully it should work.

Comment: Fails for `getIntervalls(10, 5)`, another edge case, there are only 4 groups then, cannot make 5.

Comment: @zenwraight Thank you for your response, but instead of 5 sub-intervals, your code return an array of 4 sub-intervals

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is the perfect function for that.

It allows you to get the intervals between two numbers, and the last interval always goes to the max.

```js
function getIntervals(min, max, nbIntervals) {
    let size = Math.floor((max - min) / nbIntervals);
    let result = [];

    if (size <= 0) return [min, max];

    for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervals; i++) {
        let inf = min + (i * size);
        let sup = ((inf + size) < max) ? inf + size : max;

        if (i === (nbIntervals - 1)) {
            if (sup < max) sup = max;
        }

        result.push([inf, sup]);

        if (sup >= max) break;
    }

    return result;
}
```