# Split a range of min and max in N intervals

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array of `min` and `max`. I need a solution which is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176034/split-a-range-of-number-to-a-specific-number-of-intervals) but I have a `min` value as well. For example, I have an array `[108090, 498090]`. How do I add the `min` condition in the following function?

```
function getIntervalls(max, nbIntervalls) {
    var size = Math.round((max-1) / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        var inf = i + i * size;
        var sup = inf + size < max ? inf + size: max;

        result.push([inf, sup]);
        if(inf >= max || sup >= max)break;
    }
    return result;
}
getIntervals(108090, 5)
```

The output of the above function is:

```
    [
     [
        0,
        99618
     ],
     [
        99619,
        199237
     ],
     [
        199238,
        298856
     ],
     [
        298857,
        398475
     ],
     [
        398476,
        498090
     ]
    ]
```

But I want to send the `min` value also. So my required should be like `[108090, ...], [..,..], [..,..], [..,..], [..,498090]`.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you add an example? As of now, your question is a little unclear

Comment: I see the update but I do not see an example. What I mean is, take a basic example. Say `getIntervals(100, 5)` and the expected output should be `[...]`. If there are any special cases that needs to be handled, highlight that

Comment: Okay. So what I mean is, for example, I've this array of range `[1,3]` and I want a function which takes both `min` and `max` and should take how many intervals, let's say 2 intervals. The expected output should be `[[1,2],[2,3]]` (The numbers need not to be an integer) @Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What I would do is to subtract the `min` value to the `max` value, so you are now working with numbers **linearly related** to the interval you passed as an argument.
- Then, when you are pushing the result values just add again the min value:

```js
function getIntervals(min, max, nbIntervalls) {
    max -= min;  // --------------------------> subtract min
    var size = Math.round((max-1) / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        var inf = i + i * size;
        var sup = inf + size < max ? inf + size: max;

        result.push([inf + min, sup + min]);  // --------------------> add again min
        if(inf >= max || sup >= max)break;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getIntervals(108090, 498090, 5))
```

Comment: Note, though, that this solutions ends up shorting the final group, with lengths of `[78000, 78000, 78000, 78000, 77996]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `min` condition in interval size & inf calculation as

```
function getIntervalls(min, max, nbIntervalls) {
    var size = Math.round((max-min-1) / nbIntervalls);
    var result = [];
    var inf = min;
    var sup = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < nbIntervalls; i++) {
        inf = (i == 0)? inf : sup + 1;
        sup = (inf + size) < max ? inf + size: max;
        result.push([inf, sup]);
        if(sup >= max) break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note the different size of the last group, though in this technique.

Comment: The reference in the question to another question also shows that last group will have different size. So, it will indeed be there.

Comment: Fair point.  It's not clear (with an OP comment on another answer that "The numbers need not to be an integer") what exactly is supposed to happen here, especially with the increment between one endpoint and the next startpoint in the example.  I'll add another answer with a somewhat different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this can also be done with a simple recursion.  Something like this might be all you need:

```js
const getIntervals = (min, max, count, end = min + (max - min) / count) =>
  count < 1 ? [] : [[min, end], ... getIntervals (end, max, count - 1)]

log (getIntervals (20, 62, 3))
log (getIntervals (108090, 498090, 5))
```

```html
<script>const log = (o) => console .log (JSON.stringify(o))</script>
```

We recur on the number of subgroups still to create (`count`), calculating the end of the interval using the `max`, `min`, and `count` arguments.

But this does not increment the start of one group from the end of the previous one.  We can do that with a minor adjustment:

```js
const getIntervals = (min, max, count, end = min + (max - min + 1) / count - 1) =>
  count < 1
    ? []
    : [[min, end], ... getIntervals (end + 1, max, count - 1)]

log (getIntervals (21, 62, 3))
log (getIntervals (108091, 498090, 5))
```

```html
<script>const log = (o) => console .log (JSON.stringify(o))</script>
```

This does the same thing as the above, but recurs using one more than the end of the previous group as the new minimum, rather than just using that end value as above.

Here we had to adjust the start value (or the end one) in order to get our counts correct and avoid non-integer endpoints.  We switched from `108090 - 498090` to `108091 - 498090`.  This involves knowing how many values are in the range, and ensuring the count properly divides into that number.

If for instance, we tried `getIntervals (21, 64, 6)`, we would get this:

```
[
  [21, 27.333333333333332],
  [28.333333333333332, 34.666666666666664],
  [35.666666666666664, 42],
  [43, 49.333333333333336],
  [50.333333333333336, 56.66666666666667],
  [57.66666666666667, 64]
]
```

We could do something a little different that will always work without the fractional endpoints, but will have groups that aren't exactly the same size:

```js
const getIntervals = (min, max, count, end = min + Math.ceil ((max - min + 1) / count) - 1) =>
  count < 1 ? [] : [[min, end], ... getIntervals (end + 1, max, count - 1)]

log (getIntervals (21, 62, 3))
log (getIntervals (108090, 498090, 5))
log (getIntervals (21, 64, 6))
```

```html
<script>const log = (o) => console .log (JSON.stringify(o))</script>
```

We introduce `Math.ceil`, and now `getIntervals (21, 66, 6)` returns the nicer:

```js
[ 
  [21, 28],
  [29, 36],
  [37, 43],
  [44, 50],
  [51, 57],
  [58, 64]
]
```

here we have some number of results with `n` entries followed by others with `n - 1` entries.  Here we have two groups with eight entries each followed by four others with seven each.  If we switched from `Math .ceil` to `Math .floor`, we would get the smaller groups first, and then the longer ones.  But the important thing is that all the groups are within one element of the same size as the others.

Each of these possibilities uses a simple recursion for the job.  It's pretty powerful!